# Good encoding into database, but strange chars on the webpage

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a strange problem.

In my databe, I have this data : 58 x 56 x 73 # H siège 39.

But when I display it somewhere, I get this :

```
58 x 56 x 73 # H siè{00}ge 39
                    {8f}
```

It still possible to remove the special chars ?

I tried any convert methode, but without success :(

Comment: Which encoding is used in your database? Which encoding is used for the connection to your database? Which encoding is used for the output?

Comment: UTF-8 is the default encoding

Comment: +1 there's a number of places where encoding can be screwed up. Be sure to check all the steps. (@hakre even didn't mention the charset encoding in the HTML `meta` tag)

Comment: Default encoding for what? Database? Website? Source-Code-Files? @Rijk: *Which encoding is used for the output?* should cover that. - but well you're somewhat right: Which encoding is used for reading the output? *gg*.

Comment: Well, the `output` then covers two things: the encoding used in the HTTP charset header, and the encoding in the meta tag. Sorry to nag about it, but it's really important to cover all, because miss one and your encoding is messed up again..

Comment: So : the encoding of the Database is UTF-8, the website too.

Comment: The `meta` one's also really important when you're submitting data from a form by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Try going through the list of items on this article... http://blog.loftdigital.com/blog/php-utf-8-cheatsheet
This lists the steps that are needed to make sure you're using UTF-8 from front to back in your site/application but in summary:

- Check you've got PHP's mbstring extension and you have `mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');` set in your script.
- Make sure you're running this MySQL query after connecting to your database `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");` which ensures the connection is UTF-8.
- Set the HTTP header of your output... `header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');`
- Make sure the output encoding of your HTML page is set... `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />`